# I'm trying to create a sliding gallery in AS3 in Flash CS5, but I get these errors: does it have something to do with AS3 ?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs5

> Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 1    1119: Access of possibly
>   undefined property onEnterFrame through a reference with static type
>   flash.display:DisplayObject.  Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 2
>   1119: Access of possibly undefined property _ymouse through a
>   reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject. Scene 3, Layer
>   'AS', Frame 1, Line 3    1120: Access of undefined property myVar.
>   Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 5    1119: Access of possibly
>   undefined property _ymouse through a reference with static type
>   flash.display:DisplayObject. Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 6
>   1120: Access of undefined property myVar. Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame
>   1, Line 8    1119: Access of possibly undefined property _xmouse
>   through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
>   Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 8    1120: Access of undefined
>   property myVar. Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 17   1119: Access
>   of possibly undefined property _xmouse through a reference with static
>   type flash.display:DisplayObject. Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line
>   17   1120: Access of undefined property myVar. Scene 3, Layer 'AS',
>   Frame 1, Line 24   1119: Access of possibly undefined property _xmouse
>   through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
>   Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 24   1119: Access of possibly
>   undefined property _xmouse through a reference with static type
>   flash.display:DisplayObject. Scene 3, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 24
>   1119: Access of possibly undefined property _xmouse through a
>   reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.**

the code is:

```
 enter code here
    root.onEnterFrame = function() {
    if(root._ymouse<601){
        myVar=false;
    }
    if(root._ymouse>600){
        myVar=true;
    }
    if(root._xmouse<100 && myVar==true)
    {
        imgBar.prevFrame();
        imgBar.prevFrame();
        imgBar.prevFrame();
    }
    else{
        imgBar.play;
    }
    if(root._xmouse>600 && myVar==true){
        imgBar.nextFrame();
        imgBar.nextFrame();
    }
    else{
        imgBar.play;
    }
    if(root._xmouse>100 && root._xmouse<600 && myVar==true){
    imgBar.stop();

    }
    }
```

Comment: Sure, the code is for AS2, while you attempt to compile for AS3.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in AS2. in AS3, objects use the `addEventListener` property instead of constructs like `onEnterFrame`.

Change the targeting of your project to AS2, or you can just revise the top line of code like so:

```
root.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function() {

   ... // your code

 })
```